# USB drive not recognised on windows 10 or linux

Tags: linux, windows, usb, windows-10, linux-mint

I have a usb drive that is not showing up in windows 10 or linux mint which leads me to believe that it is the drive that failed and not both of my computers. `lsusb` does not show the drive and it does not show up under `device manager` in windows. This drive has all my school work on it. Should I give up?

Comment: Does it show in Windows Disk Management

Comment: I con't find windows disk manager. Is it renamed in windows 10?

Comment: @whs I found it. No it does not show up in Disk Management.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe try `fdisk -l`? See if its listed, if it is maybe its not mounted correctly? Make a mount directory and mount it.

Can't mount? Maybe no format support, install `dosfstools` and `ntfs-3g` to support more disk formats. Install `udisks` to automount disks, if none is applicable, I'm stumped. Or you know, your flash drive is probably defective.

Comment: No it doesn't show up in `fdisk -l`. I think if it's not in `lsusb` it's not in `fdisk -l`.

Comment: Yea I figured as much. Maybe the drive is just defective. Have you tested it on different machines? You can try plugging it into windows 10 and do the whole **command prompt ----> diskpart ----> list disk** and see if its listed, I know sometimes when they're corrupted they might not show but it's worth a shot.

Comment: Nope. Just my boot drive shows up.

Comment: Try plugging it into different USB ports, if that doesn't do it then your drive is definitely gone, either that or all your USB ports are fried, which I doubt.

Comment: Well darn. Thanks for your help. Is there no way I can clone the data?

Comment: Well I mean if the drive doesn't even show up, then there is no way to reach it's contents. All the troubleshooting above is software related, so lets just assume that MAYBE it is an hardware issue, maybe a contact point is broken. Pop open the casing and check if all 4 pins are there and in tact [(USB has 4 pins)](http://pinouts.ru/visual/USB.jpg). The pins in most cases curved slightly to ensure contact with the ports, maybe its not making proper contact? Worst comes to worst solder on your own contacts, but only if you're really that desperate. Other then that, I'm stumped.

Comment: Just copy the data either to the internal disk or another USB device.